# File Reading Function only Reads First line then quits

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream

**Problem Description**

Basically, Inside of my "Roster.h" header file, i have an array of "Student" objects from the student class ( which includes the functions changeScore, SetID, setTotal,setLetterGrade). In the function that will be attached below, it is only reading the first line of data and then quitting at the while condition. I've been staring at this issue for hours now and could use a second (or third) pair of eyes. Any criticism is also appreciated, as i know that i am not the most effective programmer.It should be noted that "m_studentnum",is private data that is initialized to 0 in the constructor. Thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
void Roster::readStudentRecord(string file)
{
    ifstream in;
    string studentID;
    string line;
    int ola, cla, quiz, homework, exam, bonus, total, final = 0;

    in.open(file.c_str());

    getline(in, line);
    while (in >> studentID) {
        in >> cla >> ola >> quiz >> homework >> exam >> bonus >> total >> final;
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setID(studentID);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::CLA, cla);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::OLA, ola);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::QUIZ, quiz);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::HOMEWORK, homework);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::EXAM, exam);
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::changeScore(Student::BONUS, bonus);
        total = cla + ola + quiz + homework + exam + bonus;
        m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setTotal(total);
        if (total >= 90) {
            m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setLetterGrade('A');
        }
        else if (total >= 80 && total < 90) {
            m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setLetterGrade('B');
        }
        else if (total >= 70 && total < 80) {
            m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setLetterGrade('C');
        }
        else if (total >= 60 && total < 70) {
            m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setLetterGrade('D');
        }
        else {
            m_students[m_studentNum].Student::setLetterGrade('F');
        }
        m_studentNum++;
    }
}
```

*Data file*
-note that i am doing a getline to get read in the headline for the data column's

```
 ID         CLA   OLA   Quiz   Homework   Exam   Bonus   Total   FinalGrade   
 c088801    10    15      4         15     56       5 
 c088802     9    12      2         11     46       2 
 c088803     8    10      3         12     50       1
 c088804     5     5      3         10     53       3
 c088805     3    11      1         10     45       0 
 c088806     8    14      2         11     40      -1  
 c088807     4    12      2         12     48      -2
 c088808    10    10      3         11     36       0
 c088809     8     8      3         11     39       0
 c088810     6     9      4          9     47       3
 c088811     8     7      3         13     41       3
 c088812     4    11      3         11     37       1
```

Comment: Can you please show the first few lines of this file you're trying to read?

Comment: of course! sorry! I meant to include that haha

Comment: You should see the edit now @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Seems like you try to read 8 numbers from each line, but there are only 6. That would put `in` into a failed state, and stop further reading.

Comment: Good spot! I suppose that's why i need a second pair of eyes. Unfortunately, i am now getting the error : Unhandled exception at 0x508F4B19 (vcruntime140d.dll) in OLA1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Total" and "FinalGrade" columns are empty, and you unconditionally try to read them.

When you attempt to do that, the input will contain the "ID" from the next line, and as that is not an integer, leading to the `failbit` flag being set for the stream which causes the loop condition to be false and the loop to end.

One possible solution is to read the while line into a string, put that string into an `std::istringstream` object, and read the non-empty columns as you do now. Then try to read the possibly empty columns from the input string stream.

Another solution, if those columns are *supposed* to be empty, is to simply not read them.

Comment: Yeah, i can't believe i didn't notice i was reading those in! But i am now, unfortunately getting the error: Unhandled exception at 0x508F4B19 (vcruntime140d.dll) in OLA1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: Nevermind, it seems my issue was that i forgot to make the number of objects declared in the array of objects vary to reflect the amount in the file! All is fixed now!

Comment: @gavsta707 That's why you shouldn't be using fixed-sized array, but `std::vector` instead. They grow dynamically as you add elements to them. :)

Comment: I'm unfortunately constrained to using array's at this time. The array size was variable, I just forgot to remove some of my bug testing, which was actually restricting the objects to 9.